# How can I load dates from database table to fullcalender using PHP code? [without ajax]

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a **fullCalender** plugin and a database table with a field in the `DATETIME` datatype. Currently my calendar is just showing the events that I have hardcoded in the **calendar.js** file.

```
title: 'event_name', 
start: new Date(y, m, 16),
```

Some part of my code in calendar.js looks similar to the above section.

I have the basic knowledge in PHP and MySQL and also knowing very well that I can do it with the ajax calls. But I am in a requirement to do the same in PHP. Now how can I load the events[dates] from my table and show them in the curresponding dates in the calendar?

[Please notice that I am restricted to use **ajax** and **json**]

Some help from your side may take me through my solution. Thank you.

Comment: You do know that the AJAX call can request a PHP page that generated a JSON response? So why exactly are you restricted in the use of Ajax and JSON?

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to solve my requirement through PHP code? I need to show the calendar events with just PHP codes that fetch records from the table.

Comment: I understand, but my question is: WHY. Why don't you use AJAX.
Other than that: Show us your database structure, what have you tried already, etc.

Comment: Please read what I have quoted in [], and I also know that there is a solution according to my requirements. I am not just going for the simplest way, if so I was not supposed to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can simply pass the events array from php to javascript variable and then pass that javascript variable to the fullcalendar plugin initialization object

Somewhere in html output:

```
<script>
  var events = <?= json_encode( $eventsArray) ?>;
</script>
```

Then in `calendar.js`

```
$(function(){
   $('#myCalendarDiv').fullcalendar({
        events: events,
        /* other options */
   });
});
```

Comment: I have completed my calendar yesterday. And I checked the fullCalendar options for it. Though I think my solution almost matching to this one. Let it be a helping hand for those who seek through.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is the solution:

1. in a .htaccess add rewrite rule: RewriteRule ^calendardata.js$ calendardata.php [NC,L]
2. in calendardata.php print your data as in the calendardata.js
3. include calendardata.js in your page